# find sum combinations from two arrays

Tags: java, algorithm

There are two integer arrays, i.e. A = [2,9,8,13] and B = [5,3,1,11,4],

we knew the length of the arrays, 
i have to choose a integer from array A here let say i choose 13,

now i need to find out all the combinations of
(1 integer from array A and 1 or more than 1 integer from array B such as sum of the all the integer choosen from array A and array B is 13 or multiple of 13)

i.e.

'2' from array A and '11' from array B makes 2+11=13

'8' from array A and ('1' & '4') from array B makes 8+1+4=13

'9' from array A and ('1' & '3') from array B makes 9+1+3=13

'13' from array A and ('1','3','4','5') from array B makes 13+1+3+4+5=26

note:- have to choose only 1 integer from array A and can choose 1 or more than 1 integer from array B

only way i find out is write all the combinations in if else statment, and i definitly believe there is other way please help

Comment: Does it always have to be an multiple of 13, or is it a multiple of the integer you choose in array A? If the case is the latter, how does one choose an integer in array A?

Comment: integer choosen from array A must be greater than 9 thats the only condition, here it is only 13 which is greater than 9, if more than one element from array A is greater than 9 than we choose any of them but only one of them, any how if say it is always 13 then how will we do?

Comment: So the first example '2 from array A' it's invalid ?

Comment: yes, it is invalid

Comment: Sounds like a breadth first search, let me see if I can write it down for you.

Comment: @IvanValeriani thanks

Comment: @IvanValeriani no no sorry all the example i wrote is valid, i said one number from array A here is 13  should be greater than 9 will be choose first and after that any one integer from array  A and any subset of array B will be choosen from them only those combinations whose sum is 13 or multiple of 13 will selected, because we choose 13 intially

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is going to be any clear but here's my solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] A = new int[]{2,9,8,13};
    int[] B = new int[]{5,3,1,11,4};
    System.out.println(findMe(A, B));
}

private static List<List<Integer>> findMe(int[] A, int[] B) {

    List<List<Integer>> solutions = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    Arrays.sort(A);
    if (A[A.length - 1] > 9) { //if the greatest is greater than 9
        for (int a1 : A) { //for all the values in A
            Collection<List<Integer>> solution = findMeNow(B, a1);
            solutions.addAll(solution);
        }
    }
    return solutions;
}

private static Collection<List<Integer>> findMeNow(int[] B, int a1) {
    List<List<Integer>> lists = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(); //list of all possible combinations
    Set<List<Integer>> solutions = new HashSet<List<Integer>>(); //list of all possible combinations

    for (int b1 : B) {
        int currentSize = lists.size();
        for (int index = 0; index < currentSize; index++) {
            //for each sub list, create a copy, add the new element and add it to the mother list
            List<Integer> list = lists.get(index);
            List<Integer> copyList = new ArrayList<>(list);
            copyList.add(b1);
            lists.add(copyList); 
        }
        lists.add(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(a1, b1)));

        //Then check the sum for each of the resulting lists
        for (List<Integer> list : lists) {
            int sum = 0;
            for (Integer value : list) {
                sum += value;
            }
            if (sum % 13 == 0) {
                solutions.add(list);
            }
        }
    }
    return solutions;
}
```

The basic idea is a "breadth first search": you're actually building a tree of all possible combinations of elements of the array B, such:

1. 5
2. 5, 3, [5,3]
3. 5, 3, [5,3], [5,1], [3,1], [5,3,1], 1

etc. etc.

Worst case scenario this is equivalent to "all possible combinations" in terms of number of operations required, but on average it's going to be better.

P.S. : as you then required all the possible solutions, this is not a breadth first search anymore.

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens
 - Integer cannot be resolved to a variable
 - The method stream() is undefined for the type 
  List<Integer>

Comment: thanks, any how i also have to count combinations like
2 from array A and '1','3','4' ,'5' and ''11' from array B make
2+11+1+3+4+5=26... think i have to read more first

Comment: Made my last effort.

Comment: there are many more thing i have to do in this and it is not possible until i able to write these by myself  in very frequent maner so i have to study..btw
combinations like [9, 5, 1, 11] cannot be count, its makes 26 but it actually dont have 13+13=26 meaning there should be two subset of 13 and 13, like in this [13, 5, 3, 1, 4] 13+(1+4+3+5=13) ,  so [13, 5, 3, 1, 4] is valid but [9, 5, 1, 11] is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Here's some pseudo code:

- sort the arrays
- work along each from opposite ends (highest-lowest in one, lowest-highest the other)
- advance the pointer such that all combos are found

This gives an O(n log n) algorithm, which is far better than a O(n * n) brute force "all combos" method.

It's O(n log n) because sorting is O(n log n), but the last part is just O(n).

Comment: Why sorting B should make things better? Adding up to something multiple of 13 (or any number) is pretty random.

Comment: @ivan no, it's not "random". If you reach a number in A that exceeds 13, you know to try advancing B, which will make a lower total. It's similar logic to a merge sort, and it's O(n).

Comment: @ivan this is obviously homework, so I wanted to give OP a chance to learn, rather than spoon feeding him/her the answer.